Scheduled action for alfresco record Management
I want to create an action for a scheduled job in Alfresco 5.2. The goal is to trigger a rule for a specific period to declare a document as an archive document. I plan to achieve this by creating a Java bean or a custom XML script.
What properties should I modify to accomplish this? I'm using Alfresco Record Management 2.5b.
Thanks in advance!
i tried at first place to understand how java beans and custom scripts in Alfresco works, but when i was working on it ,i was stuck in knowing the properties to change

Search about AbstractScheduledLockedJob class and StatefulJob interface. You have to override executeJob function.

Hello Mario, thank you for your response. The problem is that I don't know which property to apply to a node so it will be declared as an archive. Do I need to change the aspect of the content node ? , because i saw in that documents declared as an archive have rm aspect .rm:content-node

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
